# What was Dante saying before he was interrupted by a nearby thug?

Tags: plot-explanation, fast-x

At Cipher’s base of operations, Dante enters by dragging two of her thugs
and stands before her while all the thugs point their guns at him. Dante
wants Cipher to help him make Dominic suffer:

> Dante: Your toys and your tech. All your boys. **'Cause you're either
> with me or you're...**

A nearby thug presses a gun to Dante’s head.

> Cipher: I don't play well with others.
>
> Dante: Then you'll have to watch who you love most die.

What was Dante saying before he was interrupted by a nearby thug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### "or you're against me."

It's the classic "world is black or white" trope. There is only two stance any named character can have, and it's either working for the protagonist or the antagonist.

A subset might replace the 'you're against me' by 'you're dead', which is implied anyway when ushered by the antagonist.

It frequently overlap with self-fulfilling prophecy... Because that third party that would have stay neutral otherwise will now have to choose